# Responsive "Tour" page has extra right space due to one section that is not responsive (only when logged out)

Tags: bug, responsive-design, tour, logout

> [image: iPhone]
> [image: Firefox]
> Left: iPhone; right: Firefox desktop
> Click either for higher resolution ([URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour))

Also makes scrolling on a mobile device funky; keeps twitching right.

To reproduce: log out. *(Thanks @Laurel)*